# ¿Cómo utilizar un Spinner como item dentro de un RecyclerView?

Tags: android

Actualmente tengo un `RecyclerView` en el que quiero añadir un `Spinner`, el cual contendrá una lista de estados. Paso el codigo de las clases q utilizo a ver si pueden ayudarme.

ConfiguracionOS.java

```
public class ConfiguracionOS extends AppCompatActivity {

String[] items;
BaseDeDatos db;
RecyclerView osView;
ConfiguracionOSHolder holder;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_configuracion_os);
    db = new BaseDeDatos(this, null, null, 1);
    osView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.configuracionOS);
    osView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    osView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    final ConfiguracionOSAdapter adapter = new ConfiguracionOSAdapter(this, listaObraSocial());
    osView.setAdapter(adapter);

    items = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.estados);
    ArrayAdapter<String> ad = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items);
    holder.estado.setAdapter(ad);
    holder.estado.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener(){
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    });
}

public ArrayList<ObraSocial> listaObraSocial() {
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + Tablas.TABLA_OS;
    SQLiteDatabase bd = db.getReadableDatabase();
    ArrayList<ObraSocial> listaOS = new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor cursor = bd.rawQuery(sql, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            String nombre = cursor.getString(1);
            String estado = cursor.getString(6);
            String coseguro = cursor.getString(7);
            listaOS.add(new ObraSocial(nombre, estado, coseguro));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
    return listaOS;
}

}
```

ConfiguracionOSAdapter.java

```
 public class ConfiguracionOSAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ConfiguracionOSHolder> implements Filterable {

Context c;
ArrayList<ObraSocial> OS, listaFiltrada;
FiltroConfiguracionOS filtro;
BaseDeDatos db;


public ConfiguracionOSAdapter(Context ctx, ArrayList<ObraSocial> OS){
    this.c=ctx;
    this.OS=OS;
    this.listaFiltrada=OS;
    db = new BaseDeDatos(ctx, null, null, 1);

}


@Override
public ConfiguracionOSHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_configuracion_os,null);

    //HOLDER
    ConfiguracionOSHolder holder=new ConfiguracionOSHolder(v);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ConfiguracionOSHolder holder, int position) {
    final ObraSocial p = OS.get(position);
    holder.nombreOS.setText(OS.get(position).getNombre());
    holder.estado.setSelection(Integer.parseInt(OS.get(position).getEstado()));
    holder.coseguroOS.setText(OS.get(position).getCoseguro());
}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return OS.size();
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    if (filtro==null){
        filtro = new FiltroConfiguracionOS(listaFiltrada, this);
    }
    return filtro;
}

}
```

ConfiguracionOSHolder

```
public class ConfiguracionOSHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
public TextView nombreOS, coseguroOS;
public Spinner estado;


public ConfiguracionOSHolder (View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    this.nombreOS = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.NombreOS);
    this.coseguroOS = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.CoseguroOS);
    this.estado = (Spinner) itemView.findViewById(R.id.spEstadosOS);

}
}
```

FiltroConfiguracionOS

```
public class FiltroConfiguracionOS extends Filter {

ConfiguracionOSAdapter adapter;
ArrayList<ObraSocial> listaOSFiltrada;


public FiltroConfiguracionOS(ArrayList<ObraSocial> listaOSFiltrada, ConfiguracionOSAdapter adapter){
    this.adapter=adapter;
    this.listaOSFiltrada=listaOSFiltrada;
}

@Override
protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
    FilterResults r = new FilterResults();
    if (constraint != null && constraint.length()>0){
        constraint = constraint.toString().toUpperCase();
        ArrayList<ObraSocial> filtroOS = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i=0; i< listaOSFiltrada.size();i++){
            if (listaOSFiltrada.get(i).getNombre().toUpperCase().contains(constraint) || listaOSFiltrada.get(i).getCuil().toUpperCase().contains(constraint)){
                filtroOS.add(listaOSFiltrada.get(i));
            }
        }
        r.count=filtroOS.size();
        r.values=filtroOS;
    }else{
        r.count=listaOSFiltrada.size();
        r.values=listaOSFiltrada;
    }
    return r;
}
@Override
protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults r) {
    adapter.OS = (ArrayList<ObraSocial>) r.values;
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

veo que tu spinner lo estas alimentando desde un recurso @array te recomendaria que mejor lo insertes directo en el XML de tu spinner

```
<Spinner 
    ...
    android:entries="@array/estados"
    ...
/>
```

y eliminas el ArrayAdapter que tienes actualmente

```
items = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.estados);
ArrayAdapter<String> ad = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items);
holder.estado.setAdapter(ad);
```

El `setOnItemSelectedListener` del spinner cambialo al metodo `onBindViewHolder` de tu clase `ConfiguracionOSAdapter` para que cada item de tu recycler tenga asignado uno diferente, quedando de la siguiente forma

```
@Override 
public void onBindViewHolder(ConfiguracionOSHolder holder, int position) {
    ...
    ...
    holder.estado.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener(){
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
         //la logica del negocio
    }
    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        //la logica del negocio
    }

    });
}
```

Con eso remueve las lineas siguientes de la asignacion del listener en tu clase `ConfiguracionOS`

```
holder.estado.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener(){

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    }
});
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por el aporte, me resolvio el problema!

Comment: Agradeceria que puntearas mi respuesta, o la marques como correcta :D

Comment: Si no es mucha molestia, te hago una nueva consulta, de que manera podria pasar datos desde el `Adapter` a una `Activity` , por ejemplo quiero mandar lo que se encuentra en `holder.estado.setSelection(Integer.parseInt(OS.get(position)‌​.getEstado()));` `holder.coseguroOS.setText(OS.get(position).getCoseguro()); , a la clase ConfiguracionOS` para luego tomar esos datos y volvarlos en mi `bd`